# How to change drawable background color from code (Java/Kotlin) file

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin, android-drawable

I have created following drawable and set it to a button background from code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <corners android:radius="8dp"/>
    <solid android:color="@color/background_profile"/>
    <padding android:left="8dp" android:top="7dp" android:right="8dp" android:bottom="6dp" />
</shape>
```

**Kotlin File**

```
  btn?.background= resources?.getDrawable(R.drawable.drawable_rewards)
```

Now i will be getting color from my service, like this `"#00000"`, and I need to update the color in `drawable_rewards.xml` file.

Is there any way we can change color of drawable file dynamically.

Comment: You could use a `MaterialButton` (which has as default rounded corners) and use `backgroundTint` to change the background color.

Answer (score 1):

```
    val wrappedDrawable: Drawable = DrawableCompat.wrap(ContextCompat.getDrawable(context!!, R.drawable.drawable_rewards)!!)
    DrawableCompat.setTint(wrappedDrawable, ContextCompat.getColor(context!!, R.color.colorPrimary))
    btn?.background = wrappedDrawable
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer is you get background of the button as drawable -> change color of drawable -> set drawable to background of the button

```
            val drawable: Drawable = buttonChange.background
            drawable.setColorFilter(Color.GREEN, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC)
            buttonChange.background = drawable
```

Answer (score 0):

```
fun View.setBgColor(color: String?) {
    val bgColor = parseColor(color) ?: return
    val drawable = if (background is InsetDrawable)
        (background as InsetDrawable).drawable
    else
        background

    when (drawable?.mutate()) { //mutate before change is important
        is ShapeDrawable -> (drawable as ShapeDrawable).paint.color = bgColor
        is GradientDrawable -> (drawable as GradientDrawable).setColor(bgColor)
        is ColorDrawable -> (drawable as ColorDrawable).color = bgColor
    }
}

fun parseColor(color: String?): Int? {
    return try {
        Color.parseColor(color)
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        null
    }
}
```